# Is there an implementation of OpenVR that does not require Steam or other DRM mechanisms?

Tags: virtual-reality, drm, oculus

I am in the early stages of planning a new spatial audio VR research project and we have a couple of choices of VR headset. Currently the Vive looks to have the slightly better audio output but looking at the documentation, the Oculus Rift's libOVR seems much cleaner from an engineering standpoint and integrates well with OpenGL.

The only way to use Vive hardware looks to be Valve's SteamVR (an implementation of the OpenVR specification) that unfortunately drags in gamer mess like Steam. I like the idea of OpenVR (one API to target many vendor implementations) but the dependency on the DRM platform is not entirely acceptable to us. Oculus has done much better here for our requirements.

I have looked into alternatives such as OpenComposite and OSVR which although are both open-source projects either only provide a wrapper around SteamVR or will not work with a Vive and instead are only aimed at playing Vive games on an Oculus Rift.

Basically what would you suggest?

1. Oculus Rift with external head phones.
2. Separate SteamVR out from Steam by patching the binary (I believe
   this will be legal in the UK if we do not share the resulting
   binary)
3. Use less consumer VR hardware (in that case, do you know of any?)
4. Use the Vive driver directly (can you point me towards
   documentation?)
5. Any other ideas I am missing?

Money is not an issue; the project is very well funded. However we don't want to produce something that is going to break once a company like Valve no longer thinks something like Windows 7 is cool (we predict the system is going to be in use for about 20 years). Usually we would start the project using Linux but VR support is embarrassingly poor from almost all companies identified, the whole environment is far more consumerist than most other types of hardware that I get involved with but VR is quite necessary for the type of results the researchers are looking for.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more searching, I just found this:

> **SteamVR In the Enterprise**
>
> SteamVR is designed to be distributed along with Steam, and receive updates via Steam. Sometimes it may be desirable to have SteamVR running without Steam, for example if a corporate policy prevents the Steam client from being installed. For inquiries about running SteamVR in standalone installations, please contact vrlicensing@valvesoftware.com.

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/steamvr/info

So I suppose the question is answered. Sorry for the noise but looking at many websites and forums, it doesn't seem that many people know this (or understand why an "enterprise" version might be important). So possibly others will find this useful!

At least now we can choose a VR headset based on the merit of the hardware rather than simply to avoid DRM / lifespan weirdness.